# How to extend screen on a secondary monitor in Android-x86?

Tags: screen, lineageos, external-display

I'm looking for a way to get two **separate** (i.e. "Extended" or split) display outputs on my Android x86 setup.

It appears that I need to modify the content of `/grub/menu.lst` file, but every guide that I have found instructs the user to either clone (i.e. "duplicate" or mirror) the displays, or worse, it instructs the user to entirely disable the internal LVDS display.  This is not what I want.

What I want is to simply have a separate output for each of my displays (two 1920x1080 monitors using HDMI.) This is something that is available on many Linux distros and even Windows.

Is what I want even possible on Android x86 at the moment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick check of [android-x86.org](https://www.android-x86.org/) shows at the bottom:

> **Development (2019/10)**
>
> **What we are working on now**
>
> - Android 10 (Q release) porting (q-x86 branch)
> - Upgrade kernel to 4.19 or newer
> - OpenGL ES hardware acceleration for intel/radeon/nvidia/amdgpu (pstglia, mauro) and virgl(robh) GPUs.
> - HDMI audio (cwhuang)
> - LineageOS integration (jjm)
> - Hardware accelerated codecs
>
> **To-Do List**
>
> - Multiple displays support
> - Better power management
> - Miracast

So the feature **Multiple display support** is on the **To-Do List** and probably dependent on OpenGL ES hardware acceleration efforts.

So as of 2019-10 the feature you want isn't available.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not yet available. You could instead switch between your screens by adding `video=LVDS-1:d` to your grub configuration file.